# Eclipse RCP translation tool

Tags: eclipse, internationalization, osgi, translation, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, which contains 600~ strings, translated to a couple of languages by myself.

The point is that I have to deliver it to the translation team to translate it to several languages in a couple of months, and I haven't found any translation tool for eclipse, which would help the translation team in its job. Is there any application which analyzes the file structure loading the messages.properties and bundles.properties files, and providing a UI to translate it safely.

If not, which would be the best way to perform this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have used the NLS tools in Eclipse, you should already have the properties files containing the translated strings.

Eclipse projects are translated through an instance of the [Babel server](http://babel.eclipse.org/babel/).

This is in itself an Eclipse hosted [project](http://www.eclipse.org/babel/).

The Babel server environment is a typical LAMP environment. You could try setting it up for your translators by following the [instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Babel_/_Server_Tool_Development_Process).

If this seems to be a lot of work for only 600 strings, it's because it is.

It is easier to use a hosted service like [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) or [Transifex](https://www.transifex.net) to cooperate with your translators.

Comment: I'll take a look at babel project, even though I ended up programming  a Java snippet to parse the .properties files and create an excel file out of them.

Answer (score 2):

Globalyzer (http://lingoport.com/globalyzer) can run as an eclipse plugin (or as a stand-alone workbench) and supports extensive internationalization activities across teams of developers and a wide variety of programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather prefer an open source solution.